# VueJS: how array method `push` can be called on an object but still works?

Tags: vuejs2, javascript-objects, vue-router

In the following `navigateToHome` method, how is it possible to use Array's  push method `Array.prototype.push` on an object (`$router`) where `$router` is the main router object:

**user.vue**

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                id: this.$route.params.id
            }
        },

        methods: {
            navigateToHome(){
                this.$router.push({path: '/'})
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**main.js - $router object is defined here**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from './App.vue'
import { routes } from './routes'

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    mode: 'history'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Comment: https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-push

Comment: @ghybs so u mean it isn't the `Array.prototype.push` method that's being used here rather `vue-routers` has an in-built push method ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it isn't the `Array.prototype.push` method, it's just a method to update the navigation history.

```
push (location: RawLocation, onComplete?: Function, onAbort?: Function) {
   this.history.push(location, onComplete, onAbort)
}
```

Take a look at the source code:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/src/index.js#L141

Answer (score 0):

just pass a string instead of object. Have you tried: this?

```
this.$router.push('/')
```